# Change a HTML attribute: xml:lang

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

Here's my html code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

I want to change the attribute of `xml:lang="en"` into `xml:lang="Foobar"` and the next `lang="en"` into `xml:lang="Foobar"`

Does this parser work? [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)
As i read the documentation, it should goes like this:

```
$html = file_get_html('D:\xampp\htdocs\hmtl\index.html'); 
$value = $html->lang;
$html->href = 'Foobar';
```

But, it's not working.
What am i missing here?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents()` does not generate an HTML DOM. It simply reads the file as plain text.

Therefore, before you can use `$html->lang` or `$html->href`, you need to convert the plain text into a DOM object structure. As described in the link you provided, you would need to use the function `str_get_html()`, between `file_get_contents()` and trying to use the DOM object.

Alternatively, the same page also lists an entirely object-oriented way to do it:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('test.htm');
```

...where you would obviously replace `test.htm` with your file path.

Comment: there's been a mistake in my question, it's not file_get_contents() it's file_get_html(); done editing the question..